# cp -r equivalent in windows command prompt without error code 1

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to perform the equivalent of `cp -r` on linux in a windows batch script. The general solution seems to be robocopy (or xcopy [which has been deprecated](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)).

So performing the operation:

```
robocopy source_folder destination_folder
```

copies the source_folder (and the subitems) into destination_folder. If destination folder doesn't exist it will create it BUT, it will return an exit code of 1. How do I perform this copy operation without getting an error code?

(in other words doing the same as `cp -r` does on *nix systems).

EDIT:
to clarify what `cp -r` does it is copy recursively, I want to go from

```
folder
|-subfolder_a
    |-my_file.txt
```

to:

```
folder
|-subfolder_a
    |-my_file.txt
|-subfolder_b
    |-my_file.txt
```

where both `my_file.txt`'s are identical, this would be done (from within `folder`) on *nix with `cp -r subfolder_a subfolder_b`. I attempted to do it on windows with `robocopy subfolder_a subfolder_b` but got error_code 1. I would like to do this without any error codes (and without ignoring the error code).

Comment: Windows also has the 1> and 2> like on *nix.  The equivalent of /dev/null is NUL:

Comment: If you want to set your `%errorlevel%` back to 0, do `cmd /c exit /b 0`

Comment: Try explaining what `cp -r` does - don't assume that everyone knows *nix as well as you do. `cp` means what? copy? compare?

Comment: @Magoo I've edited the question to clarify. oversight on my part.

Comment: @MikeH-R Robocopy sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 1 if a file is successfully copied.  It has nothing to do with whether it created a directory.  [See this list](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) of Robocopy exit codes.

Comment: @rojo Thank you, I misunderstood and thought it was an error code, if you put that as an answer I'll accept it (otherwise I'll add it myself and close this).

Comment: `xcopy` may be "deprecated" but even Microsoft may have a hard time removing it - it's incorporated in so many existing scripts, including their own that it would be more trouble than it's worth to withdraw it. Well, IMHO, anyway.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for the info, I may just use xcopy next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robocopy sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 1 if a file is successfully copied.  It has nothing to do with whether it created a directory.  [See this list](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) of Robocopy exit codes.

Just as an academic exercise, you can set the exit code back to 0 with `cmd /c exit /b 0`.  If you want to combine it into the `robocopy` command, do something like this:

```
robocopy src dest && (echo Nothing copied) || cmd /c exit /b 0
```

And as Magoo points out, `xcopy` probably isn't going to go away any time soon.

```
xcopy src dest\
```

returns an exit code of 0 on success, non-zero on fail.  According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), `xcopy` returns the following exit codes:

> `Exit code Description`
>
> `0         Files were copied without error.`
>
> `1         No files were found to copy.`
>
> `2         The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.`
>
> `4         Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.`
>
> `5         Disk write error occurred.`

Comment: slightly off-topic comment about comments. AFAIAA, OP will receive notifications of **all** responses (answers or comments) so no need to direct to OP. The "owner" of an answer will also receive notification of responses to the answer posted.

Comment: @Magoo I just wanted to express that my comment was directed explicitly to the OP and not to the immediately previous commenter.  Force of habit.  It was intended to be more a visual cue than a trigger for message notification.  In this case, I agree that it was redundant; but in general, is it inappropriate?  S.E. usually hides the autocomplete in situations where the redundancy is obvious.